# How to serialize interface default property?

Tags: c#, .net-core, interface, system.text.json

This question is resurrected, because I was wrong in comment "My bad". 
This issue is there, or I miss something. For popular demand here is a minimal reproducable example:

[minimal reproducable example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dniZBH)

---

I have an interface with a default property:

```
public interface INotification
{
    // ...
    Severity Severity { get; set; } // Severity is an Enum
    // ...
    public string SeverityName => Severity.ToString().ToLower();
}
```

I have an implementation class

```
public class Notification : INotification
{
    // ...
    public Severity Severity { get; set; }
    // ...
    // This class does not override default implementation of SeverityName
}
```

**Question**

The Notification class does not have a `SeverityName` property... this was surprising, but I can live with that, accessing to the notification instance via the `INotification` interface.

However, I would like to serialize this class with `System.Text.Json`. How can I serialize `SeverityName` property too?

Comment: Did you try to serialize the instance of the class? Was there any problem? Which serializer you refer to? xml? json? ...?

Comment: @HimBromBeere OP mentioned `System.Text.Json`

Comment: Have you tried it? What didn't work? This question is very vague

Comment: I am referring  System.Text.Json, the Core serializer so not Newtonsoft. Yes, the serializer does not see the default property ** because the Notification instance seems to have no such a property**

Comment: So where is your code where you do this?

Comment: @liam, the code is inside deep in a infra which uses SignalR to communicate with the browser, but I see the json text, and the default property is not there...

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], please?

Comment: @liam it seems you are correct to insist to see the code. It turns out, that it may be the SignalR (internal?) serialization, and not the System.Text.Json. I must see the `_hub.Clients.Clients(connectionIds).SendAsync("JsRuntimeCall", identifier, args)` MS code how the args are serialized. It may be some custome binary? serialization. Anyway, as I wrote I am surprized that the Notification instance not having the property, probably this is the reason why (any?) serializer disregards it when serializing.

Comment: My bad.  System.Text.Json  serializes the property... I am stuck with the SignalR issue. I am going to delete this post, sorry for using anyone's time.

Comment: No worries @g.pickardou, shows the power of a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with `System.Text.Json` in .NET Core 3.1 other than by writing a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to) for `Notification`. The serializer serializes the public properties of a type, but default interface properties are **not implemented as class properties**, instead they're implemented through some sort of extension mechanism. See the spec: *[default interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods)*

> Add support for *virtual extension methods* - methods in interfaces with concrete implementations. .

Only when the default interface property is **overridden** does an instance property actually get added to the implementing concrete type, and thereby become serializable.

For confirmation, if we modify the classes from your [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dniZBH) as follows:

```
public interface INotification
{
    Severity Severity { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }

    static string MakeDefaultSeverityName<TNotification>(TNotification notification) where TNotification : INotification => notification?.Severity.ToString().ToLower();

    public string SeverityName => MakeDefaultSeverityName(this);
}

public class Notification : INotification
{
    public Severity Severity { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationWithOverride : Notification
{
    public string SeverityName => INotification.MakeDefaultSeverityName(this);
}
```

And print out the properties and methods of both types using reflection:

```
Console.WriteLine("Properties of {0}: {1}", typeof(TNotification).Name, string.Join(", ", typeof(TNotification).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Select(p => p.Name)));
Console.WriteLine("Methods of {0}: {1}", typeof(TNotification).Name, string.Join(", ", typeof(TNotification).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Select(p => p.Name)));
```

We get the following results for `Notification`:

```
Properties of Notification: Severity, Message
Methods of Notification: get_Severity, set_Severity, get_Message, set_Message, GetType, MemberwiseClone, Finalize, ToString, Equals, GetHashCode
```

And for `NotificationWithOverride`:

```
Properties of NotificationWithOverride: SeverityName, Severity, Message
Methods of NotificationWithOverride: get_SeverityName, get_Severity, set_Severity, get_Message, set_Message, GetType, MemberwiseClone, Finalize, ToString, Equals, GetHashCode
```

Notice there's just no instance property or method corresponding to `SeverityName` in `Notification` -- but there is in `NotificationWithOverride`.  Lacking a property to serialize, the serializer does not output a `SeverityName` value.

Notes:

1. `System.Text.Json` is consistent with other serializers in this respect; both it and Json.NET generate exactly the same JSON:

   - `{"Severity":0,"Message":"Message"}` for `Notification`.
   - `{"SeverityName":"info","Severity":0,"Message":"Message"}` for `NotificationWithOverride`.
2. With Json.NET it might be possible to create a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that automatically adds in the missing default properties, but `System.Text.Json` does not have public access to its contract resolver; for confirmation see the question *[System.Text.Json API is there something like IContractResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182)* to which the answer is, *not currently*.
3. In c# 8.0 it is not possible for to override a default interface method in a concrete class and call the base interface method.  See *[How can I call the default method instead of the concrete implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59748097/3744182)*, *[Making member virtual prevents calling default interface implementation and causes StackOverflowException in C# 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59387322/37441828)* and *[Default interface implementations and `base()` calls](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-04-29.md#default-interface-implementations-and-base-calls)* for details.

   To work around this I added a **`static`** interface method to `INotification` that encapsulates the default logic, then called it from both the default interface instance method and the override class method.

A demo fiddle that shows the above can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g7gUfv).

Comment: many thanks for the details. Obviously my knowledge on interface methods has blanks.