# What does it mean to define a default interface implementation as 'virtual'?

Tags: c#, interface, virtual, default-implementation

I have an interface with a virtual method with a default implementation:

```
interface I
{
  public virtual void M() => ...
}
```

I would like to override it like so and call the default implementation:

```
class A : I
{
  public override void M() { base.M(); ... }
}
```

This doesn't compile. So what does it mean to mark an interface with 'virtual' if you can't override it?

Comment: I believe (but I'm not sure, and I haven't found any proof) that the `virtual` you show in your first code block was not allowed until recently (likely with the onset of default interface implementations).  Now, it is apparently allowed, but I'm guessing it's pretty much ignored.  The semantics of _default interface implementations_ are different from the implementation of a method marked `virtual` in a base class.  In your second code block, you are not _overriding_ the implementation, you are just providing your own implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making member virtual prevents calling default interface implementation and causes StackOverflowException in C# 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387322/making-member-virtual-prevents-calling-default-interface-implementation-and-caus)

Comment: You can't do this. Once the method is implementated you cannot call the default implementation *at all*.

Comment: @Charlieface slightly different, I'm interested in what virtual does when declared in the actual interface, not in an implementing class.

Comment: It's by definition `virtual` unless it's `sealed` or `private` so it's basically an unnecessary extra modifier as it's the default anyway https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#modifiers-in-interfaces